# VB.NET System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.'

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, type-conversion

I have an Access database connected to my project and what i'm trying to do here is to show some values in a combobox connected to a field on datagridview.

This is the error that i am getting

```
System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.'
```

Here is the code

```
   Private Sub form_inventory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'InventoryManager2DataSet.Sub_Category' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Sub_CategoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventoryManager2DataSet.Sub_Category)

        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'InventoryManager2DataSet.Sub_Category' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Sub_CategoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventoryManager2DataSet.Sub_Category)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'InventoryManager2DataSet.Inventory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.InventoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventoryManager2DataSet.Inventory)
        Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn8.DisplayMember = "Category"
        Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn8.ValueMember = "ID"
        Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn8.DataSource = Sub_CategoryBindingSource


        With Sub_CategoryComboBox
            .DataSource = Sub_CategoryBindingSource
            .DisplayMember = "Category"
            .ValueMember = "Id"
        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub Sub_CategoryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Sub_CategoryComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Me.Sub_CategoryComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            InventoryBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
        Else
            InventoryBindingSource.Filter = $"convert[Sub Category] = '{Me.Sub_CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue}'"
        End If
    End Sub
```

This part of the code triggers the error

```
 InventoryBindingSource.Filter = $"convert[Sub Category] = '{Me.Sub_CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue}'"
```

I can get this to work an a clean combobox with no connection, but i cannot get it to work when its connected to the field.

- Sub_Category is a Table
- Sub Category is a Long Integer
- Category is a Short text

Sub Category is a look-up field from Sub_Category Table which contains the Category field.

Here it is visualized:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You said the value of the combobox will be the `Id` property

```
With Sub_CategoryComboBox
    .DataSource = Sub_CategoryBindingSource
    .DisplayMember = "Category"
    .ValueMember = "Id" ' This line!
End With
```

And then you tried to compare the value of the combobox (which is an `Id`) with a textual field.

I don't now what should be your business logic, but I suspect maybe it's what you need:

```
With Sub_CategoryComboBox
    .DataSource = Sub_CategoryBindingSource
    .DisplayMember = "Category"
    .ValueMember = "Category" ' Changed!
End With
```

Comment: This doesn't work i have already tried it, also ignore the convert in InventoryBindingSource.Filter = $"convert[Sub Category] = '{Me.Sub_CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue}'" i forgot to delete it